# Using minecraft server with screen

Tags: arch-linux, console, minecraft

I would like to have remote console access to my minecraft/bukkit server. I want it running in a local console, but at the same time accesible via ssh/telnet. I have heard that `screen` can supply the feature I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have screen installed --I'm not sure if Arch has it by default-- it's fairly simple process.

In your Tekkit directory type:

```
$ screen -dmS myTekkitServer ./StartScript.sh
```

If you run the command above, it will launch your server in a screen session and place it in the background.

`screen -list` will display the currently running screens and

```
$ screen -r myTekkitServer
```

will connect to your detached screen.

Also, if you need to detach from a session once you're attached, just type: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I am assuming this works with ssh/telnet correct?

Comment: @wolfo9999 Yes, it will work perfectly fine through SSH and/or Telnet. You should really disable/block telnet if you have it on though; it is terribly insecure.

Comment: Correct. One of the main reasons for using screen is that it allows someone to seamlessly reconnect ssh/telnet sessions.

Comment: Well thanks for helping! :D I don't use tekkit, but same concept applies because I use a start.sh script to set custom memory allocation.