# SSH Screens with Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft

I have just started to learn ssh. I installed everything needed, started my minecraft server, can join it, see all commands though console, ect. But when I leave the screen and close the Terminal I cant seem to get back to it. If I try reconnection straight after I disconnect (I type exit while in screen) I can connect. I just type screen -R

I would like to know how do I get back to the screen where I can see my minecraft servers console..

Thanks in advance!
Rob

Comment: Hwo do you disconnect from the screen? Do you use strg +a +d (holding strg and pressing a then quickly after that d)

Answer (score 2):

When you using screen and detaching from it (ctrl A+D) you can reconnect via:

```
# screen -ls
There are screens on:
    23322.pts-1.sql (Detached)
    27808.pts-7.sql (Detached)
    16293.pts-2.sql (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

To reconnect use:

```
# screen -r 23322.pts-1.sql
```

With Minecraft server i recommend use ABM: 
http://www.curse.com/server-mods/minecraft/ascii-bukkit-menu - very simple tool to manage your minecraft server.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that you are exiting / closing screen instead of detaching, or just hitting ctrl+d (logging out).

You need to detach first.  ctrl+a d to detach.

+1 for using screen as an ssh/linux newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/582437/443279), which says:

```
$: screen -list
```

will display the currently running screens and

```
$: screen -r myTekkitServer
```

will connect to your detached screen.